# I can't drop my database or alter my tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

Something weird just happened, I have a database and I dropped the whole DB once since it was practically messy, afterwards, I created it again and managed to find more errors so I dropped it again but this time, the query went on for so long, I had to interrupt it. But every time I interrupt it, Workbench crashes instantly. Afterwhich, I tried altering tables instead but it does the same thing now. What should I do?

Update: I can't drop tables as well now. I think anything related to schema changes makes it hang and load forever.
Update: Apparently, I can still perform other normal database operations on other databases just no the one I'm working on though. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried forcing an unexpected reboot of the database? I'd have a better suggestion but my crystal ball is still at the mechanic's place and they cannot *predict* when they'll be able to return it to me.

Comment: How do I do that? None of my other databases can alter table schemas too. I think my workbench might be bugged or something.

Comment: Workbench, and GUIs, sometimes aren't a replacement for good old CLI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably messed up your schema entirely. Schemas/dbs in MySQL are just folders in the data directory. So try removing the folder with the corrupt db (move to a place outside the data folder) and see if things go back to normal.